# voltage level shift inside controller for some communication

Tags: microchip

I am working on dspic controller and which is operating at 5 V. how can I check in datasheet about does it will provide me 3.3V for some operations or not?

Comment: You could try reading the data sheet possibly?

Comment: where would it be mentioned? in electrical charactristics or somewhere else

Comment: Try asking in English.  I don't know what dialect of Gibberish *"in datasheet about does it will provide me"* is, but it's certainly not English.

Answer (score -1):

All PIC datasheets have a section at the end called *electrical characteristics*.  You open the PDF document, go to that section, and read it.

This really should have been obvious.